Image of Special Orthogonal Groups over a ring $R$ under the map induced by $R \to R/J$.
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit and $S \in R^{n \times n}$ a matrix over $R$ such that $S$ is invertible in $R^{n\times n}$ and $S^t = S$. Define $\mathrm{SO}_n(R,S) = \{M \in R^{n \times n} \mid M^tSM=S \text{ and } \det(M) = 1\}$, which is a group under matrix multiplication.
Given a proper ideal $J$ of $R$, let $\pi : R^{n \times n} \to (R/J)^{n \times n}$ be the canonical projection and $\tilde{\pi} : \mathrm{SO}_n(R,S) \to \mathrm{SO}_n(R/J,\pi(S))$ the restriction of $\pi$ to these groups. Is it true that $\tilde{\pi}$ is surjective? Maybe with some condition on $R$?
More specifically, I want to know if this is true when $R$ is a DVR and
$$
S = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & I\\
I & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
for $n$ even and
$$
S = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & I\\
0 & I & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
for $n$ odd. But I believe this holds for a more general class of rings, like local rings or PIDs, because I've found similar results for $\mathrm{SL}_n(R)$ and $\mathrm{Sp}_{2n}(R)$. I just can't find a reference for this. If someone can point out any references, I would be glad.
